# not able to login using sqlcmd in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, tcp, sql-server-2008-r2

Related to SQL Server 2008 R2 Named Instance
I have created a configuration file using the setup. I have switched SQL Server Browser service to Automatic . I have used Windows Authentication mode and used BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS account as SQL Server Administrators.

The scenario goes like this...i sysprep my machine and then change administrator name and machine name.After that I install SQL Server 2008 R2 using the configuration file created above and install other softwares too.

I am not able to connect to the SQL server using sqlcmd -S tcp:127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS. Using tcp is a requirement, i dont want to use named pipes.
I enabled TCP\IP protocol under SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for SQLEXPRESS and disabled others.

I get the error 
HResult 0xFFFFFFFF, Level 16, State 1
SQL Server Network Interfaces: Server doesn't support requested protocol [xFFFFF
FFF].
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or in
stance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server
. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and i
f SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see
 SQL Server Books Online..
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired.

Comment: Are you able to connect to your instance in SSMS? Make sure also that browser service is started.

Comment: The browser service is started...I installed SSMS and checked but i wasnt able to connect even through it. It seems the new administrator name does not get added to SQL administrators.

Comment: Is SSMS able to show your instance in server selection menu?

Comment: If this is newly installed machine make sure Windows Firewall does not block port 1433 for default instance and 1434 for browser service.

Comment: SSMS is able to show the instance in server selection menu. The firewall in machine is off.

Comment: Do a hit and trial:- Enable all the services in SQL Server Services and Enable(Shared Memory and TCP/IP protocols) in all the options.
(1) Sql Native client 10.0
(2) Sql server network Config
(3) SQL Native Client 10.0 (32-bit)